# UWP: Add Equalizer to MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, uwp, streaming, media, windows-media-player

I have a UWP App for web radio streaming (for electronic music). Therefore, I want to add an equalizer, that each user can change it on their own. 
Is there an easy possibility to add such an equalizer to the MediaPlayer.

I found something about the AudioGraph possibility. But with this way, I'll lose the MediaPlayer features (like current Track / Artist on LockScreen and the Thumbnail).

Hope someone can help me
Thanks
Christian

Comment: Currently, MediaPlayer could not use AudioGraph directly. You could try to use the [MediaPlayer.AddAudioEffect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.addaudioeffect?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Media_Playback_MediaPlayer_AddAudioEffect_System_String_System_Boolean_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IPropertySet_) method to add an audio effect of equalizer to the playback stream of the MediaPlayer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to [custom audio effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-audio-effects) to a clip in a MediaComposition which can be previewed in a MediaPlayerElement.

Comment: Hi YanGu, is it possible to add this as a feature request to the new implementation Project Reunion?

Comment: You could submit a feedback about requesting the feature in **Feedback Hub**.